# Character in Java game not responding

Tags: java

I have been following Java Game Tutorials and go stuck on one, that one is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RolMRqekV3o&list=PL6E90696571998DC2 I have an issue where my character does not respond to the arrow keys. If you could help it would be great. My code:

```
package theJavaHubGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    int x, y, xDirection = 10, yDirection = 10;
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;
    Image face;

    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){

                move();

                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");

        }
    }

    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 15);

        public void move(){
            x += xDirection;
            y += yDirection;

            if(x <= 0)
                x = 0;
            if (x >= 200)
                x = 200;
            if(y <= 50)
                y = 50;
            if(y >= 250)
                y = 250;
        }

        public void setXDirection(int xdir){
            xDirection = xdir;
        }

        public void setYDirection(int ydir){
            yDirection = ydir;
        }
        public class AL extends KeyAdapter{
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

                if(keyCode == e.VK_LEFT){
                    setXDirection(-1);
                    System.out.println("Key Pressed");
                }

                if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT){ 
                    setXDirection(+1);

                }

                if(keyCode == e.VK_UP){
                    setYDirection(-1);
                }

                if(keyCode == e.VK_DOWN){
                    setYDirection(+1);
                }

            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

                if(keyCode == e.VK_LEFT){
                    setXDirection(0);
                    System.out.println("Key Pressed");
                }
                if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT){
                    setXDirection(0);
                }
                if(keyCode == e.VK_UP){
                    setYDirection(0);
                }
                if(keyCode == e.VK_DOWN){
                    setYDirection(0);
                }
            }
        }

    public Main(){

        //Load Images
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("F:/Android/Workspace/TheJavaHubGame/src/theJavaHubGame/Face.gif");
        face = i.getImage();

        //Game Properties
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        setTitle("Java Game");
        setSize(250,250);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        x=150;
        y=150;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage,0,0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        g.drawString("Super-Mega Ball Bouncer II", 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
        g.drawImage(face, x, y, this);
        repaint();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main jg = new Main();
        //Threads
        Thread t1 = new Thread();
        t1.start();
    }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to make a game, maybe you shold consider using JavaFX, which tries to exploit hardware acceleration (GPU).

Comment: Use a game engine man!

Comment: I want to learn how to do it in vanilla java. I just need help making the character move when I press the arrow keys, that's all.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to listen to the people telling you to use an engine--for most "real" games, an engine saves you a lot of busywork and boilerplate (not to mention bugs), but if you're just learning to write games for the first time, writing one from scratch like this will teach you how everything really works. After you've written a few small games this way, you'll probably want to move on to a game engine.

Answer (score 4):

This may be the culprit:

```
Main jg = new Main();
//Threads
Thread t1 = new Thread();
t1.start();
```

You didn't pass a `Runnable` to the `Thread`, so the thread isn't actually doing anything. Without an update thread, nothing in your game will move. Try this:

```
Main jg = new Main();
//Threads
Thread t1 = new Thread(jg);
t1.start();
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch.  Take all the reps.

Comment: @user163505 Don't forget to mark the answer as "Accepted" when you can.  :)  Also, do you get *why* it works and what the problem was?